# Used Code Plugin in Eclipse

Tags: swing, eclipse-plugin, code-analysis

I tried to analyze a swing application. It's an old project and it has been growing over years, so it's very hard to read the code. Now we should redesign the application.

Now I'm looking for an Eclipse plugin which could me support to understand this application. Here what kind of plugin I'm looking for:

1. start application from Eclipse in debug mode
2. I run in the application to a point
3. I start the record in Eclipse plugin
4. I run some kind of business logic in the application
5. I stop the record
6. the tool shows me, which code is used or not during the record

Does someone know if this kind of plugin exists?

Cheers
Julia

Answer (score 0):

Not a specific plugin, but you can get something what you want by smartly placing breakpoints:
For example to find where the action listener code is for a button, set a break point in the ActionEvent constructor just before you press the button. Then you can step forward until you get to the listener.

You could also use VisualVM (or other profiler) to do CPU sampling while you take your action and then look in which code the CPU time was spent (in the EDT for the Swing GUI specifically).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a coverage tool that can be switched on and off at runtime. I don't think this is possible with Emma or Cobertura; best guess is to use these for unit tests (or small test applications that only use partial functionality) and hide any unused types to get partial views. But that may not work well when you want to understand GUI actions and responses.

Even if it is not exactly part of your question I would recommend to have a look into the [X-Ray plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/x-ray-software-visualization) which helped me a lot with a legacy application.

Oh, and [Eclipsecolorer Profiler](http://eclipsecolorer.sourceforge.net/index_profiler.html) helped... but the project is not active any more.